# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. Python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
first = int(list1[0] + list1[1]) 

a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19,a20,a21,a22,a23 = map(float, list1)

if first == 11:
            c = con.execute("SELECT Centroid FROM Centroid WHERE ItemID = 1")
            centroid = c.fetchone()
            AA = (min(a1, a2) * centroid) + (pow(a3,2))
            BB = (min(a1, a2) + a3)
            WA = AA/BB
            print (WA)
```

Above is my code. My problem now is I get an error:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

The variables I used (a1,a2,a3,centriod) is a type of float.

Comment: Does `map` return a generator in Python 3? That would cause `min(<generator>, None) * 1.4`, and that would explain the error. Also, list comprehensions seem to be favored over `map`, anyway. Try replacing `map(...)` with `[float(x) for x in list1]`

Comment: Are you sure about the types? Did you check? Especially check `centroid`. Why do you expect it to be a `float`, when you get it from an SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get first element of centroid out of tuple for use as value as `type(centroid) is tuple` is `True`. Use:

```
centroid = c.fetchone()[0]
```